# Can I transmit a beacon signal from iPhone device while at the same time scanning nearby beacons?

Tags: ios, iphone, geolocation, ibeacon, proximity

Is it possible to transmit and receive beacon signals at the same time using an iPhone device acting as a beacon?

What I am doing right now:

```
LocationUpdateController *monitoringController;

if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {

    // initiate iBeacon broadcasting mode
    monitoringController = [[LocationUpdateController alloc] initWithLocationMode:ApplicationModePeripheral];

} else {

    // initate peripheral iBeacon monitoring mode
    monitoringController = [[LocationUpdateController alloc] initWithLocationMode:ApplicationModeRegionMonitoring];
}
```

Now, I am creating 2 instance of the `LocationUpdateController` and initialize both of them, but only broadcasting mode is working and it is not monitoring any beacon. What is wrong in the code?

```
LocationUpdateController *monitoringController;
LocationUpdateController *monitoringController1;

// initiate iBeacon broadcasting mode
monitoringController = [[LocationUpdateController alloc] initWithLocationMode:ApplicationModePeripheral];

// initate peripheral iBeacon monitoring mode
monitoringController1 = [[LocationUpdateController alloc] initWithLocationMode:ApplicationModeRegionMonitoring];
}
```

Comment: What is LocationUpdateController?  Is this supplied by a third party iOS framework?

Comment: Yes, Its third party controller which I am using.

Comment: You probably need to post a link to the documentation or source code for that third party controller for us to help.